# How to use php variable insisde system command

Tags: php

How do I use a PHP5 variable inside a system() call

$dir = '/etc/somedir';

eg `system("ls $dir")`

I think I'm missing something

I am actually passing a variable from a post

**e.g.**

```
$username = $_POST[username];
```

to a system call

system("processData --user $username --pass $password");

this isn't working, so i trivialised down to a simple
example

Comment: pretty much exactly that - how are you determining that it doesn't work?

Comment: Be sure to take note of sAc's mention of escaping the shell command. Passing a raw user supplied ($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, etc) input to a shell command is *even more dangerous* than SQL injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it fine except that you are missing semi-colon (`;`)

```
system("ls $dir");
```

You can also do like:

```
system("ls" . $dir);
```

**Note:**

> When allowing user-supplied data to be
>   passed to this function, use
>   `escapeshellarg()` or
>   `escapeshellcmd()` to ensure that
>   users cannot trick the system into
>   executing arbitrary commands.

Comment: +1 for mentioning shell security. Too many web sites have been destroyed this way.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are not.. could you extend your example? are there any errors returned? what does the system() function return?

you should keep in mind that `system()` returns only the last line of the run command.

also, instead of 'ls' you can use a built-in php function like [dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php) or [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

---